# Getting started with node.js and express

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I know how it sounds but this is straight from their websites and this is the very first step for us noobs trying out Node with Express. How do you consolidate the two? Thanks, you guys are awesome!

NODE:

```
const http = require('http');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

EXPRESS:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`))
```

Comment: You don't need both of them. Just use the express one and it should work?

Comment: What do you mean by "consolidate"?

Answer (score 0):

When you  call `app.listen(3000, ...)`, it will register itself as a listener
function to the Nodejs’s native http server ,something like below

```
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

So you see express is build on top of node js http module (and some other modules too).

There is a good article [here](https://blog.laputa.io/understanding-expressjs-d5ef4f4646c8) which elaborates the express js functioning,do have a look.